# Can anyone identify this "Hummer" bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike, women-specific

I bought this bike from the thrift store the other day and have had no luck identifying it myself through web searches. The only things I know about it is that it's a womens bike, it's had a paint job it's a 10 speed, the main name on it says "Hummer",  and the smaller name on it says "brinkman". If anyone knows something about this bike it would be of great help! Thanks!!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't help with identification but I notice that both tyre valves are at odd angles. I recommend you adjust them so they're both perpendicular to the rim, since that puts less stress on them and makes them less likely to tear off. If you deflate the tyres, you should be able to move the tyre and inner tube around the wheel rim (they'll only need to go a short distance) and then pump the tyres up again.

Comment: It's a fairly classic "girl's bike" from the 70s.  The kickstand seems to be welded, which would be consistent with Schwinn, but not hard proof.  The Schwinn pictures show eyelets for the rear brake cable, but these are missing in the photos above.  I have seen the Hummer and brinkman names before, but don't recall where.

Comment: Man, that's a comfy looking seat! My tush still hurts from this weekends ride on my rooty local trails.

Comment: @GaryBak Eh. The American market seems to be full of bikes with these enormously wide seats. Having ridden one (for several months, even), I found it rather uncomfortable. Sitting on something so wide restricts the movement of your legs, like sitting on a bench.

Comment: @DanielRHicks You're probably thinking of the "Hummer" branded folding mountain bikes that [Montague made in the noughties](https://www.montaguebikes.com/folding-bikes-blog/2014/09/montague-bikes-how-to-spot-a-counterfeit/).

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Those sofa-seats, you can't even call them saddles, are somewhat dangerous because they lack the nose of a bicycle saddle, which has an important guiding function through contact with the inner thighs. Making the cycle lose side stability on faster downhills. Although I firmly doubt that these will ever do that.

Comment: 2 @DavidRicherby: The brake levers are also turned inwards at a rather odd angle bringing the infamous suicide levers into an even odder position with a strong risk of hitting them with the knee when standing on the pedals. I would correct that as well or have it corrected by a mechanic.

Comment: @Carel - Yeah, I hadn't noticed the saddle.  Clearly an "upgrade" from the original.

Answer (score 7):

Some components have clearly been replaced, but it looks a lot like a 1970's Schwinn Varsity Sport
[image: 1970's Schwinn Varsity Sport]
[image]

More info [here](https://bikehistory.org/bikes/varsity/)

The fork rake didn't look quite right, so I kept on googling and found an ebay advert with what claims to be a 1983 model that looks an even better fit
[image]

Comment: Good detective work!

Comment: I'm guessing Hummer is a random sticker/transfer applied by a previous owner.  Locally, brinkman is a brand of chicken, but is also a normal surname.  Could it be the surname of a previous owner?

Comment: The frame and fork is not from a Schwinn. The welded kickstand assembly is different. Seat cluster, lack of cable braze-ons, and rear dropouts are all different.